# SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Tags: linux, drivers, php, redirection, odbc

I am running a PHP script on a RedHat server using Teradatas ODBC drivers.

```
<?php

$conn = odbc_connect("Teradata", "username", "password");
$result = odbc_exec($conn, 'SELECT count(*) FROM table');

while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= odbc_num_fields($result); $i++) {
        echo "Result is ".odbc_result($result,$i);
    }
}

?>
```

I have run `strace` on the script and found that it's looking for the `.ini` files which hold the DNS information in the wrong location as well as putting a `.` before the file name.

```
open("/home/a-taslam/.odbcinst.ini", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

It should be looking for the file at `/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbcinst.ini`

Does anyone know how to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set and export the `ODBCSYSINI` environment variable --

```
export ODBCSYSINI=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/
```

or

```
set ODBCSYSINI=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/ ; export ODBCSYSINI
```

Note -- this environment variable must be set for `php` when it's running, whether `php` inherits the setting from its launch environment, or you add this setting to the PHP configuration files.